# Doctrine - unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with doctrine. I digged heavily into google, tried all tips and still nothing.

My bash says it can't load dynamic library.

I have checked my php.ini path and than checked all configs but still no idea what to change.

And of course I did uncommented 'extension_dir' path so this is not a case.

No idea. I am using Windows 10.

I will appreciate any help!

[Screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lj4ca69y6lvf1he/AABG9Wn4Nfj1sWXe5ZMvg1D1a?dl=0) (can't do more than 2 links until at least 10 rep)

Comment: What does the `phpinfo()` say for PDO?

Comment: I see that's the problem. https://www.dropbox.com/home/doctrine%20issue?preview=pdo+drivers.PNG